# PHP Can't use 'not' in array with http_build_query()

Tags: php, http

I'm a completely beginner at `PHP` and I tried searching for the solution to this but I can't seem to find it.

Whenever I try to use `http_build_query()` on my array, it turns the `$note` variable into a symbol (¬e). I was just wondering if there is any way I can still use note without changing the variable name.

Ex.

```
<?php
 $vars = array(
             'book' => 'humpty',
             'newspaper' => 'onion',
             'note' => 'not working');

 $query = http_build_query($vars);
 echo $query;
?>
```

The expected output is: `book=humpty&newspaper=onion&note=not+working`

The actual output is: `book=humpty&newspaper=onion¬e=not+working`

Thank you.

Comment: working fine for me https://3v4l.org/JK5dq

Comment: The PHP code is correct. It's just that your browser thinks you want to use the HTML special character `&not;` and interprets it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the problem you're having. It's caused since http_build_query() makes the 'not' into a ¬ symbol which is known as a NOT SIGN.

Try this instead:

```
$vars = array(
         'book' => 'humpty',
         'newspaper' => 'onion',
         'note' => 'not working');

 $query = http_build_query($vars);
 $fixed_query = htmlspecialchars($query, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
 echo $fixed_query;
```